# Compare date with current date in java using sql

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to compare a SQL date with the current date.

I figured out how to compare two SQL dates but I couldn't extract the current date.

```
java.sql.Date xxx = new java.sql.Date(jdatechooser1.getDate().getTime());
java.sql.Date yyy = new java.sql.Date(jdatechooser2.getDate().getTime());

if (yyy.after(xxx)) {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

Comment: `new Date().after(xxx)`?

Comment: the problem is sqldate doesn't have such constructor date() !!!

Comment: No, but `java.util.Date` does

Comment: cant import both sql and util date at the same time

Comment: `new java.util.Date().after(xxx)`, you can use a fully qualified name instead. This is not a new problem

Comment: i used already thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you must create a `java.util.Date` object with empty constructor. Then give the long value which can be get by `getTime()` method, to the java.sql.Date constructor.

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

Uses the system date instead: `System.currentTimeMillis()`

```
java.sql.Date dateToBeChecked= new java.sql.Date(jdatechooser1.getDate().getTime());
java.sql.Date systemDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

if(dateToBeChecked.after(systemDate)){
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

But since it's `long` values you don't need to transform anything to an object and can do this instead:

```
if(jdatechooser1.getDate().getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis()){
  System.out.println("ok");
}
```